# TypeScript error in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, constructor, typescript, undefined-function

I have a simple TypeScript file as follows:

```
module HouseOfSynergy
{
    export module Library
    {
        export class Version
        {
            private _Major: number = 0;
            private _Minor: number = 0;
            private _Build: number = 0;
            private _Revision: number = 0;

            public get Major(): number { return (this._Major); }
            public get Minor(): number { return (this._Minor); }
            public get Build(): number { return (this._Build); }
            public get Revision(): number { return (this._Revision); }

            constructor(major: number, minor: number, build: number, revision: number)
            {
                this._Major = major;
                this._Minor = minor;
                this._Build = build;
                this._Revision = revision;
            }

            public toString(): string
            {
                return (this._Major.toString() + "." + this._Minor.toString() + "." + this._Build.toString() + "." + this._Revision.toString());
            }

            private static _Current: HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version = new HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
            public static get Current(): HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version { return (HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version._Current); }
        }
    }
}
```

The static property `Current` is called from an HTML file as follows:

```
alert(HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version.Current.toString());
```

Google Chrome produces the following errors:

TypeScript:
[image]
[image]

HTML/JavaScript:
[image]
[image]

I have tried converting the static property to a function but keep getting the same error. Even declaring an instance of the `Version` class `new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)` produces the same error. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Here is the produced JavaScript:

```
var HouseOfSynergy;
(function (HouseOfSynergy) {
    var Library;
    (function (Library) {
        var Version = (function () {
            function Version(major, minor, build, revision) {
                this._Major = 0;
                this._Minor = 0;
                this._Build = 0;
                this._Revision = 0;
                this._Major = major;
                this._Minor = minor;
                this._Build = build;
                this._Revision = revision;
            }
            Object.defineProperty(Version.prototype, "Major", {
                get: function () { return (this._Major); },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            Object.defineProperty(Version.prototype, "Minor", {
                get: function () { return (this._Minor); },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            Object.defineProperty(Version.prototype, "Build", {
                get: function () { return (this._Build); },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            Object.defineProperty(Version.prototype, "Revision", {
                get: function () { return (this._Revision); },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            Version.prototype.toString = function () {
                return (this._Major.toString() + "." + this._Minor.toString() + "." + this._Build.toString() + "." + this._Revision.toString());
            };
            Object.defineProperty(Version, "Current", {
                get: function () { return (HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version._Current); },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            Version._Current = new HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
            return Version;
        }());
        Library.Version = Version;
    })(Library = HouseOfSynergy.Library || (HouseOfSynergy.Library = {}));
})(HouseOfSynergy || (HouseOfSynergy = {}));
```

Comment: At the end of the day, Chrome is working with the javascript that the TypeScript compiler produces, we are going to need to see that javascript to be able to help.  Once we know what that javascript looks like and where the problem is in that, then hopefully we can help you fix up your typescript.  You might also want to include which version of TypeScript you're using and what your `--target` setting is (for tsc.exe).

Comment: I'm not sure about the typescript, but transpiling it to JS, `HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version` is being instantiated before `Version` class assigned to the `Library` object. So you should better of doing `new Version` instead, for the assignment `private static _Current: HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @CodingGorilla: Generated JavaScript added. I'm using TS version 1.8.5 which is the latest as of today.

Comment: @rahilwazir: Thanks. That worked. Is there a way to forcefully assign `Version` to the `Library` module in the code? This was rather annoying.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I'm not sure why do you wanna do that, because the reference will remain same whether you use nested instantiation or standalone. Still for JS do `HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version = Version` before `Version._Current` assignment line

Comment: @rahilwazir: Thanks. You should post your original comment as an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing code within a namespace, you can omit the full namespace. Not only does this make code less verbose and more readable... it will also work...

```
module HouseOfSynergy
{
    export module Library
    {
        export class Version
        {   
            public static get Current(): Version { return (Version._Current); }

            private static _Current: Version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);

            public get Major(): number { return (this.major); }
            public get Minor(): number { return (this.minor); }
            public get Build(): number { return (this.build); }
            public get Revision(): number { return (this.revision); }

            constructor(private major: number, private minor: number, private build: number, private revision: number)
            {
            }

            public toString(): string
            {
                return (this.major + "." + this.minor + "." + this.build + "." + this.revision);
            }
        }
    }
}

alert(HouseOfSynergy.Library.Version.Current.toString());
```

Comment: This is definitely more readable. Although, experimenting with variations had me convinced that the order of declarations was important. Your example appears to negates that. I'll play around with it further and revert back if necessary. Thanks.